# Has anyone tried to prepare chemically competent Mycobacteria?

Tags: transformation

Bacterial species like *E. coli* are easy to transform using a variety of methods, including both chemical transformation and electroporation. Chemical transformation is especially nice to use as it can be done in high throughput. I'd like to start working with *Mycobacterium smegmatis*, though, and have only been able to find electroporation-based transformation methods like the one described [here](http://www.jove.com/video/761/electroporation-of-mycobacteria). Can chemically-competent mycobacteria be prepared? If so, are they just very inefficient? Is it worth testing some *E. coli*-specific methods with mycobacteria?

Comment: There was no link to the paper. So I added one.

Comment: Mycobacteria are *very* different from *E. coli*. I would be rather surprised if you could adapt the methods without a lot of customization. What's wrong with electroporation?